# Alternative expression for theta function

Tags: fourier-series, heat-equation, theta-functions

I've been trying to re-express the particular theta function
$$\theta(r)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\cos(nr)\exp(-n^2/\lambda)$$
in the form
$$\theta(r)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\alpha_n\exp(-\lambda(r-2\pi n)^2/\beta)$$
for some $\alpha_n$ and $\beta$. It seems to me that it should be possible, based on intuition from considering diffusion over $S^1$: the $\theta$ function is a fundamental solution of such a system, but it also seems we should be able to take the fundamental solution over $\mathbb{R}$ and sum over the concentrations at $\{r+2\pi n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ to arrive at the same solution.

I've considered writing the cosine term in terms of complex exponentials, for which I get
$$\theta(r)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(inr-n^2/\lambda),$$
but from here I don't see how to proceed.

Would greatly appreciate any help! If my assumption is incorrect, would love to hear where my logic is lacking.

Comment: You want to find the Fourier series (or Poisson summation formula) for the $2\pi$-periodic function $f(r)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(-\lambda (r-2\pi n)^2)$, knowing the Fourier transform of the Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @reuns! Here's my solution:

For a Fourier transform $S$ of a function $s$ defined by $\displaystyle S(f)\triangleq\int_\mathbb{R}s(x)e^{-i2\pi fx}dx$, we have that
$$s_{2\pi}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{2\pi}S\left(\frac{k}{2\pi}\right)e^{ikx},$$
Eqn. 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), where $\displaystyle s_{2\pi}(x)\triangleq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}s(x+2\pi n).$ We have that the Fourier transform of the Gaussian $s(x)=e^{-\lambda x^2}$ is
$$S(f) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}e^{-(\pi f)^2/\lambda},$$
and so we have that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(-\lambda(r+2\pi n)^2)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi\lambda}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4\lambda}k^2\right)e^{ikr},$$
which reduces to
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\exp(-\lambda(r+2\pi n)^2)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi\lambda}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\cos(kr)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4\lambda}k^2\right).$$
Finally, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f4i4qxvwif) is a Desmos plot.